# Updated Crystal Reports runtime on IIS server, now getting ambiguous error

Tags: iis, crystal-reports, web-config

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30560: 'ReportDocument' is ambiguous in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 36:   Private Sub showPDF()
Line 37: 
Line 38:       Dim rpt As New ReportDocument()
Line 39:       Dim strPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/InvoiceReport2.rpt")
```

I first noticed this issue when I had 2 versions of Crystal in my `web.config`, I have since removed them and I no longer get this error while debugging on my local machine.  When i push my code to the IIS server, I still get this error.

I have already deleted the virtual directory -> stopped the web server and application pools -> restarted the web server and application pools -> added the virtual directory back.  I will rename my application if necessary but hope that is not the only answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was being caused by having a different version of Crystal in the `web.config` of the root directory of the web site.  Once removed, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

**as per below code i have just stop 13.0 version of crystal report and application works ok so check in web.config that ,no more than 1 crystal report version have declared and if its there then remove one**

-->
        
        -->
        
        -->